# Read and Write from 2D array in VHDL

Tags: arrays, 2d, vhdl

I'm trying to read and write from the 2D array I created: M. It seems to be working, but the first Read Operations always fails. I always populate the array before reading.

Sometimes when I read, there will be value there that was never inputted. I'm fairly new to VHDL programming, but is my 2D array correct? Am I accessing and writing to it correctly?

When EN and WEN are 1, I want to write. 
When EN is 1 and WEN is 0, I want to read.

Values from data_in go into the array. And when I'm 'reading' them they get outputted to data_out.

TIA, and if I haven't provided enough information please let me know.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY data_mem IS
PORT(
clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
addr : IN UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0);
data_in : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
wen : IN STD_LOGIC;
en : IN STD_LOGIC;
data_out : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0));
END data_mem;

ARCHITECTURE Description OF data_mem IS
signal tOUT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
type array2D is array (7 downto 0,31 downto 0) of std_logic;
signal M : array2D;

BEGIN
PROCESS(clk)
Begin
    if (falling_edge(clk)) then
        if (en = '1') then
            if (wen = '0') then
                --Read. data_out = M[addr]
                for i in 0 to 31 loop
                    tOUT(i) <= M(to_integer(addr),i);
                end loop;
            else
                --Write M[addr] <= data_in && data_out = 0
                for i in 0 to 31 loop
                    M(to_integer(addr),i) <= data_in(i);
                end loop;
                tOUT <= (tOUT'range => '0');
            end if;
        else
            --Function: N/A data_out = 0
            tOUT <= (tOUT'range => '0');
        end if; 
    end if;
END PROCESS;

data_out <= tOUT;
END Description;
```

Comment: Since you're only ever accessing entire words, your code will be significantly simpler if you make your type declaration `type array2D is array (7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)`. You won't have to do those for loops to pull out each 32-bit word that way. Same effect, though maybe not technically a "2D array".

Comment: That being said, I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. It might be in whatever higher-level code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 1):

The addr signal should be *2 downto 0*, or the array *(255 downto 0, 31 downto 0)*.

When addr is converted to integer, it takes a value ranging from 0 to 255 (8 bits). The first dimension of the array is defined as *7 downto 0*, thus when addr if 8 or more, it is outside the range and comportement is undefined.

Moreover, I recommend against using 2D arrays as at least Xilinx does not synthesize them properly. Arrays of std_logic_vector or records works fine. As suggested in comments, you can use:

```
type array is array(7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
...
    tOUT <= M(to_integer(addr));
    ...
    M(to_integer(addr)) <= data_in;
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the array declaration to match that. 

I haven't finished the top-level yet, I'm just using a Quartus waveform file to test it. The output problem might have just been a hardware issue. Since the random numbers in the output would resemble the previous values.

Comment: Here's what the simulation looks like. There a random number in the output for some reason
http://s10.postimg.org/safhowki0/Capture.jpg